# Icepdf change annotation position?

Tags: swing, icepdf

In `Icepdf`, how do I display `SquareAnnotationComponent` at the position shown in the image below?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this.  The first way is similar to this example [ViewerComponentExample](https://github.com/pcorless/icepdf/blob/master/examples/component/src/main/java/org/icepdf/examples/component/ViewerComponentExample.java).   The idea is you get an instance of the ViewerPropertiesManager and set the desired property.  In your case you would set the following property.

```
properties.getPreferences().putBoolean(ViewerPropertiesManager.PROPERTY_SHOW_TOOLBAR_ANNOTATION_RECTANGLE, true);
```

Second option is to update the key value of *application.toolbar.annotation.rectangle.enabled* in the ICEpdfDefaults.properties file and rebuild the viewer jar.

There are newer versions of the library available, I'd recommend giving 7.1.3 a try.

Comment: Thank @pcorless, i'm using org.icepdf.os:icepdf-core:6.2.2 lib, and all their example link has 404 not found. This example https://github.com/pcorless/icepdf/ help me a lot.